# Unit test for method that uses a service

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm writing a unit tests for a component. One of it's methods uses a service and it's giving me a `cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error.

I've seen how to call a service in the test but I'm trying to use a method that calls a service outside of my spec file.

**Spec**

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
        imports: [...],
        declarations: [MyComponent],
        providers: [...],
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should save', () => {
    ...
    component.myMethod();
  });

});
```

**Component**

```
  public myMethod() {
      ...
      this.myService.something(this.item).then((resp) => {
       // Error comes from here
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in multiple ways, by mocking services method:

- Using spyOn

```
it('should save', () => {
  const service = TestBed.inject(MyService);
  spyOn(service , 'something').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve('test'));
  component.myMethod();
});
```

- [Mocking service](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-with-a-dependency)

```
let userServiceStub: Partial<MyService>;

myServiceStub = {
  something: () => Promise.resolve('test'),
};

// configureTestingModule
providers: [
  { provide: MyService, useValue: MockService(myServiceStub ) }
]
```

- Using [ng-mocks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks) (my favourite)

```
// configureTestingModule
providers: [
  MockProvider(MyService, { something: () => Promise.resolve('test') })
]
```

There are other ways, but one of these should do.